# Why does the plot legend lose markers when doing multiple plots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statsmodels

A simple pandas plot produces expected output with a circle marker on the legend:

```
import io
import pandas
import matplotlib
import statsmodels
import matplotlib.pyplot
import statsmodels.tsa.api

cause = "Malignant neoplasms"
csv_data = """Year,CrudeRate
1999,197.0
2000,196.5
2001,194.3
2002,193.7
2003,192.0
2004,189.2
2005,189.3
2006,187.6
2007,186.9
2008,186.0
2009,185.0
2010,186.2
2011,185.1
2012,185.6
2013,185.0
2014,185.6
2015,185.4
2016,185.1
2017,183.9
"""

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col="Year", parse_dates=True)
df.plot(color="black", marker="o", legend=True)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image: Simple pandas plot]

Notice that the "CrudeRate" legend item is a straight line with a circle marker which is correct.

However, if I add some additional plots for Holt linear exponential smoothing functions, the legend loses the circle marker:

```
import io
import pandas
import matplotlib
import statsmodels
import matplotlib.pyplot
import statsmodels.tsa.api

cause = "Malignant neoplasms"
csv_data = """Year,CrudeRate
1999,197.0
2000,196.5
2001,194.3
2002,193.7
2003,192.0
2004,189.2
2005,189.3
2006,187.6
2007,186.9
2008,186.0
2009,185.0
2010,186.2
2011,185.1
2012,185.6
2013,185.0
2014,185.6
2015,185.4
2016,185.1
2017,183.9
"""

def ets_non_seasonal(df, color, predict, exponential=False, damped=False, damping_slope=0.98):
  fit = statsmodels.tsa.api.Holt(df, exponential=exponential, damped=damped).fit(damping_slope=damping_slope if damped else None)
  fit.fittedvalues.plot(color=color, style="--")
  title = "ETS(A,{}{},N)".format("M" if exponential else "A", "_d" if damped else "")
  forecast = fit.forecast(predict).rename("${}$".format(title))
  forecast.plot(color=color, legend=True, style="--")

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col="Year", parse_dates=True)
df.plot(color="black", marker="o", legend=True)
ets_non_seasonal(df, "red", 5, exponential=False, damped=False, damping_slope=0.98)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image: Legend missing marker]

Notice that the "CrudeRate" legend item is only a straight line without the circle marker.

What is causing the legend in the second case to lose its circle marker for the main plot?

Comment: Using `matplotlib.pyplot.legend()`, now you are aware that you are plotting 3 different graphs (Crude Rate, Fitted Values, and your Forecast), correct?

Also, generally, `matplotlib.pyplot` is imported as follow `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `matplotlib.pyplot.legend()` before `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` will solve your problem.

Since you are plotting 3 graphs, and from my understanding you want only 2 labels in the legend, we pass `label='_nolegend_'` to `fit.fittedvalues.plot()`. If we do not do so, we will have a 3rd label in the graph legend with a value of `None`.

```
import io
import pandas
import matplotlib
import statsmodels
import matplotlib.pyplot
import statsmodels.tsa.api

cause = "Malignant neoplasms"
csv_data = """Year,CrudeRate
1999,197.0
2000,196.5
2001,194.3
2002,193.7
2003,192.0
2004,189.2
2005,189.3
2006,187.6
2007,186.9
2008,186.0
2009,185.0
2010,186.2
2011,185.1
2012,185.6
2013,185.0
2014,185.6
2015,185.4
2016,185.1
2017,183.9
"""

def ets_non_seasonal(df, color, predict, exponential=False, damped=False, damping_slope=0.98):
  fit = statsmodels.tsa.api.Holt(df, exponential=exponential, damped=damped).fit(damping_slope=damping_slope if damped else None)
  fit.fittedvalues.plot(color=color, style="--", label='_nolegend_')
  title = "ETS(A,{}{},N)".format("M" if exponential else "A", "_d" if damped else "")
  forecast = fit.forecast(predict).rename("${}$".format(title))
  forecast.plot(color=color, legend=True, style="--")

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col="Year", parse_dates=True)
df.plot(color="black", marker="o", legend=True)
ets_non_seasonal(df, "red", 5, exponential=False, damped=False, damping_slope=0.98)
matplotlib.pyplot.legend()
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image]

On a side note, to make it easier for you to write you code, it is good practice to import `matplotlib.pyplot` as follow `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: Thank you. It's not clear to me exactly why this fixes it: is this a bug in matplotlib, or just a design limitation? In any case, I'm happy :-) I have certainly seen the convention of using module aliases and I simply don't personally like it; I find the verbose syntax is more self-explanatory. The only time I see a benefit to using aliases is to avoid loading an entire module for performance reasons.

Comment: I would not be able to answer, but this maybe an interesting question to ask. Of course, whatever works best for you. :) Just keep in mind that if you collaborate with others on projects, they may expect to see conventions used (especially conventions used in libraries documentation).